# 3 condition AND in grep

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to conduct a search of three conditions joined with AND with `grep`

I am able to search for `b,` AND `ghkj` like this:

```
grep -e "b,.*ghkj"
```

but I am unable to search for `b,` AND `ghkj` AND `uuuuuu` like this:

```
grep -e "b,.*ghkj.*uuuuuu"
```

How do I create a 3 condition AND search with `grep`?

Comment: it's hard to understand what you are writing about. Add some input samples and post the desired result

Comment: I understand what the question is about, I have to wait for the current proposed edit to clear the queue first

Comment: I need to serche in file linux wiht three condition AND not OR

Comment: you could also use awk which supports logical AND... for ex: `awk '/abc/ && /123/ && /foo/' file` .. easy to add not conditions as well... for ex: `awk '/abc/ && !/123/ && /foo/' file`

Comment: @Sundeep You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

There is no AND operator in grep (or any regex language afaik)

```
grep -E -e 'aaa.*bbb'
```

Matches any line that includes 'aaa' followed by any number of characters (`.*`) and then 'bbb', this simulates an AND in that it matches lines containing 'aaa' and 'bbb' in that order, but it will not match 'bbbaaa'. To get all lines containing 'aaa' and 'bbb' we can use an OR (`|`) to cover all possible cases.

```
grep -E -e 'aaa.*bbb|bbb.*aaa'
```

This strategy does not extend well to 3 or more clauses though, since the number of cases grows exponentially.

Instead we can use pipes to achieve an AND.

```
grep -E -e 'aaa' file | grep -E -e 'bbb' | grep -E -e 'ccc'
```

1. The first grep finds all lines in `file` containing 'aaa' and outputs them.
2. The second grep takes this output and finds all lines containing 'bbb' and outputs them.
3. The third grep takes this output and finds all lines containing 'ccc' and outputs them.

The final output will only be lines from `file` which contain 'aaa' AND 'bbb' AND 'ccc' in any order.

Comment: that exactly what I need to do 

 shell_exec('grep -E -e '.$yeasrs.'  /var/test/test2/ '.$name_file | grep -E -e '.$id.' | grep -E -e '.$id_user.'"); 

not work

Comment: the shell won't expand variables wrapped in single quotes, try using `'grep -E -e "$years" "/var/test/test2/$name_file" | grep -E -e "$id" | grep -E -e "$id_user"'`

Comment: Sorry, thats outside the scope of the question, there are a bunch of explanations of quoting and using variables with grep, if those don't answer your question, ask another one

Comment: If this answer showed you how to solve the exact problem you asked about, please upvote and accept